# How to sync data from mongodb to elastic6.4 using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch

with large volume of mongodb data need to synchronize with elastic

I tried mono-connector and it is not currently supported by MongoDB, Inc and not support elastic 6.*

Please help me to implement Logstash to sync  ElasticSearch with my MongoDB

https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb

Will this work with elastic 6.4?

Comment: no one to help?